# Can we regard "lecture" as a monomorphemic word in Modern English?

Tags: morphology

Judging by the derivative chain lecture appears to be the root itself (comp. lecture, lectur-er, lecture-ship, un-lectur-ed etc.). But I'm not sure if it can be divided by analogy with failure (to fail), creature (to create), departure (to depart) etc. The question is whether "lecture" functions as a monomorphemic or bimorphemic word in Modern English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one can safely deem "lecture" as monomorphemic, as its etymology, by [Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=lecture&searchmode=none), shows:

> late 14c., "action of reading, that which is read," from M.L. lectura "a reading, lecture,"

As you can see, it comes from the Latin word *lectura*, which means that "lecture" is itself the root word, as its Latin root isn't something like *lec* or *tur*. This can be compared to other monomorphemic words, such as ["wait"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=wait&searchmode=none) as well as ["man"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=man&searchmode=none)

Comment: Of course in Latin it is not monomorphemic, but that is irrelevant.